# Finding the density function of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

The question asks given that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ are independent normal variables with mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. Find the $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$$

So I know that the normal distribution is
$\dfrac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\left(-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)}$.

Since they are independently and identically distributed then to get the joint would just be
$$
  f(x) = \left(\dfrac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\left(-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)}\right)^n $$

And then you would multiply by $\dfrac{1}{n}$.
I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with pdfs given by $f_X$ and $f_Y$ respectively, the pdf of $X+Y$, $f_{X+Y}$, is given by the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$: $f_{X+Y}(x)=f_X*f_Y(x):=\int\limits_{\mathbf R} f_X(t)f_Y(x-t)\,\mathrm dt$. This can be used to show that the sum of independent normal random variables is normally distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th sum of independent normals is normal, and a constant times a normal is normal. Let $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n)$. Then $\overline{X}$ is normally distributed, mean $\mu$, and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

The value of the mean follows from the linearity of expectation. As to the variance of $\overline{X}$, it is $\frac{1}{n^2}$ times the variance of $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$. And the variance of a sum of **independent** random variables is the sum of their variances.

Thus the density function of $\overline{X}$ is equal to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\tau^2}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\tau^2)},$$ 
where $\tau^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the joint density with the density of the sum of the $n$ random variables divided by $n$.

Given that the random variables are independently and identically distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the joint density of the $n$ variables is indeed the product of the individual densities. You do not multiply this result by $\frac{1}{n}$.

On the other hand, the density of the sum of the $n$ **normal** variables will be a single **normal** density with mean $n\mu$ and variance $n\sigma^2$.

The mean of the sum of random variable is the sum of the means (linearity property of expectation):-
$$E\{\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\}=\sum_{i=1}^NE\{X_i\}=n\mu$$

As the random variables are independent, the variance of the sum is equal to the sum of the variances:- 
$$Var\{\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\}=\sum_{i=1}^NVar\{X_i\}=n\sigma^2$$

If you were to divide the sum by $n$, the result would have mean $\mu$ but variance $\large\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ (multiplying a random variable by factor $k$ results in the mean being scaled by $k$ but the variance being scaled by $k^2$). The density of the scaled sum will have mean $\mu$ and variance $\large\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

Thus the density of $\large\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ will be $$\large f(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{n(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Comment: How would you justify that mathematically? Would you use the moment generating method to calculate the pdf?

Comment: To calculate the pdf, you wouldn't have to use the moment generating method. The sum of normal random variables results in another normal random variable - this is a property of the normal distribution. The Normal distribution is completely defined by the first two moments: the mean and variance. So the process of adding the random variables then dividing the sum transforms the mean and variance (as described in the answer). The mathematical form of the pdf remains the same - the mean and variance simply change.